# Identity Range Management problem

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

Recently upgraded from SQL Server 2000 to 2008.  When we recreated the Merge Replication we decided to use Automatic Identity Range Management (since it is now the default in 2008).  The problem is that we keep running out of ID ranges on the publisher for our busier tables.

My main question is this:  **When and how does the publisher get a new range assigned?**

Our subscribers are set to synchronize every night.  I assumed that during this synchronization the identity ranges would be adjusted on both the publisher and subscribers (as the thresholds are exceeded).  This does not seem to be the case.

I understand how the thresholds work and they are set with plenty of room for error so long as the identity ranges are adjusted at least once a day.

Comment: Our subscribers synchronize via `sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent` (one agent per subscriber).  There is also a snapshot agent that runs every 14 days.  Do we need to add a merge agent that specifically runs against the publisher?  If so, how?